# How do I select an id nested inside a data attribute using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

I have a delete button that when clicked triggers a popover. In that popover I have the real link doing the deleting. I want to select the id of the link inside that `data-content`(Bootstrap) of of the popover.

I have multiple elements on a page that could be deleted so I don't know their IDs beforehand but they have the same class, so I generate an ID, then use `$(this).attr('id')` to select the particular delete link.

This is the popover button and the link inside the data-content

```
<button tabindex="0" role="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-toggle="popover"           
   data-placement="top" data-html="true" data-content="<a class='btn delete-draw text-danger' 
   id='[generatedId]'>Delete Draw</a>">Delete Draw
</button>
```

Now this is the jquery code

```
$(".delete-draw").click(function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    var drawId = $(this).attr("id");
    // make ajax delete call
 });
```

If I move the `id` and `.delete-draw` class to the outer popover button, it works well. So I'm thinking it has to do with the `id` of the `a` tag being nested in another `data-attribute`

Comment: So what is it you want to do? What do you need help with? The content of `data-content` is not rendered so `$('.delete-draw')` would not select the `a` element.

Comment: @PeterKA I believe my question title sums up what I need. However, kindly check my comment on Swati's answer. Thanks

Comment: Also the data-content is rendered fine `data-content="<a class='btn delete-draw text-danger' id='d313bd31-becb-11ea-b47a-560002b57c7a'>` That's from page source

Comment: As it is, the `anchor` tag is not rendered, in other words `<a .....>Delete Draw</a>` is not part of the pages HTML markup, hence your question. You do have to use a delegated event.

Comment: [Understanding Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since that `anchor` tag markup is added to the page after `DOM Ready` event here is how you would select that tag:

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete-draw', function() {
    let id = this.id;
    console.log( id );
});
```

Comment: Ah this already makes perfect sense. I totally forgot about the DOM being ready

Comment: Glad I could be of help. Enjoy!!

Answer (score 0):

You can passed the `custom` attribute inside `$()` and then access the `id` value.

**Demo Code** :

```js
$(".btn-sm").click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  //getting custom attribute
  var drawId = $(this).attr("data-content");
  //selecting id using that elemnt
  var ids =$(drawId).attr('id')
  console.log(ids)

 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button tabindex="0" role="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-html="true" data-content="<a class='btn delete-draw text-danger' 
   id='1324'>Delete Draw</a>">Delete Draw
</button>
```

Comment: Upvoted since this is a solution to a similar problem, but I dont what the ajax firing after clicking the popover button. This select the id quite alright, but it selects it immediately the popover is clicked. I want the selection to happen only when the `a` tag inside the data-content is clicked

Comment: So you are showing content of a tag in your pop up ? How? Can you elaborate that?

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue of binding event listener to the `<a>` when it is actually inserted in the popover

Comment: Ahh ..yes @charlietfl .. I think I misunderstood the question :)